# Confusion in updating data from multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a list of checkboxes on a form, which updates the user's status.
I want to do like, when new users are selected in the checkbox, then they get inserted in DB, otherwise, if something is unchecked, but it is active in the database, then it should be deactivated.

**I adopted:**
I took 2 arrays, first from database, where I get which users are active.
And second from the submitted form, which values are **checked**, but don't know how I will calculate that which data to be inserted and which one should be made inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the ones in the database and if they are not checked by the user then remove them.

```
foreach ($from_db as $in_db) {
    if ( ! in_array($in_db, $from_user) {
        // TODO: remove $in_db from db
    }
}
```

Then loop through the ones checked by the user and if they are not in the database add them.

```
foreach ($from_user as $add_to_db) {
    if ( ! in_array($add_to_db, $from_db) {
        // TODO: add $add_to_db to db
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare two arrays, and walk through one check each item in another. You may turn one into a hash table for faster checking when walking through another.

```
for each user_from_client {
  if (user_from_client in db) {
    if (!user_from_client.checked)
      db.deactivate(user_from_client);
  } else {
    if (user_from_client.checked)
      db.insert(user_from_client);
  }
}
```